# Create new release of application without go live current version

Tags: android, google-play, release, google-play-console

I have an application that I can go live but I'm still not click go live. Can I create new release without Go live the current version. And If I create new release version, what happen with current version that ready to go live.

Comment: do you want to schedule a release??
https://www.techaheadcorp.com/blog/you-can-now-schedule-the-launch-of-your-android-app-updates/

Comment: @PembaTamang No, I want to cancel current app version which is ready to go live because I found some bug. And update new app version without publish current version which I can click go live.

Comment: is it saved as a draft?? Im sure u can discard it

Comment: @PembaTamang think it 's not a draft since I already submit update this app. [I use Timed Publishing]

Comment: you can just delete previously uploaded apk and can upload new one on release management

Comment: talk to the support team
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en
 or publish your app, I'm sure you have push notifications enabled, let the users know that they need to update to the latest version where the bug has been fixed

Comment: is that so?? give him some links @Danialclarc

Comment: @Danialclarc I don't know hot to delete latest update apk.